# Are all PSN PSP games compatible with PS Vita?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, psn, psp, ps-vita

It is well known the PS Vita is not backwards compatible with any UMD-based PSP games, as it uses a different, not compatible storage media. Sony also confirmed that PSP games purchased through PSN's PlayStation Store will be compatible with PS Vita.

My question is: are all PSN PSP games compatible with PS Vita? If not, which games are specifically NOT compatible with Vita (preferably a list)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No sorry, but Sony have said they are aiming to make as many compatible as possible. [**Heres a list**](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/335548/a-list-of-vita-compatible-psp-games/) of all the initially compatible games.

I found [**this FAQ**](http://www.slashgear.com/sony-answers-all-your-ps-vita-questions-09158375/) which answers a few questions but I'm not sure if this is the definate answer you were looking for. It says (about half way down):

> Q: Is PS Vita compatible with other PlayStation platform games like PS3, PS2, or PSP? Do you have any plan to support other PlayStation platforms in the future?
>
> A: Users can play PSP titles, minis and PSone classics titles **which are offered on PS Store**. We do no have any plans to make PS Vita compatible with PS3 or PS2 titles at this point.
>
> Q: Is PS Vita compatible with PSP content other than games such as video and comics available on PlayStation Store?
>
> A: SCE plans to make those content available on PS Vita.
>
> Q: Can PS Vita users continue using their save data for PSP games that they have also downloaded from PlayStation Store to PS Vita?
>
> A: We are looking into the opportunity to do so.

The **bolded** would *suggest* no, only confirmed titles would be supported however this is really vague and still doesn't completely prove or disprove that the use unsupported games will work. However Sony have already said UMDs aren't supported and if  the only way to get the PSP games onto your Vita is through the store then I highly doubt any unofficially supported games will work.

Sorry for not providing any concrete definiative sources I just couldn't find any.

Comment: Thanks for the list. Do you know of any sources that could confirm or deny the information that all the PSP games and/or minis not included in the list are NOT compatible with PS Vita?

Comment: @sarmackie I've added some more information to my answer but there doesn't really seem to be any information on non-officially supported games anywhere. That kind of information will start to appear a few weeks after release I imagine once people can test it. Sorry.

Comment: Ok thank you for the additions. For me it's a fully satisfactory answer, I guess people will post here their answers in future in case problems with certain PSN PSP games would appear.

Comment: @sarmackie No problem, yeah - once more information arises I'm sure the answers will turn up here too :-)

Comment: I was totally wrong; just got my Vita and there are definitely PSP games from the PSN that are not currently available for the PS Vita. Examples are Patchwork Heroes and Patapon 3, PSP games NOT available for the Vita in the store.

Comment: @BenBrocka - is it known whether these games are just temporarily unavailable or is it confirmed they will NOT be supported?

Comment: @sarmackie that I don't know. I would imagine support will be expanded sort of like how PS1 games were made to work on the PS3 AND PSP, but I don't know of any official statement. I certainly *hope* support will increase, they're probably just games that were particularly easy to port (low hardware requirements)

Comment: @BenBrocka just to be clear the answer I provided was correct? There are indeed PSN PSP games on the store that are NOT compatible with the Vita? Or they are? The reason I'm asking is my answer has been unchecked...

Comment: You're correct, there are PSN PSP games that are not compatible with the vita right now.

Answer (score 3):

It appears **you CAN install most* PSP games availible on the PSN onto your Vita *if you have a PS3***.

Download the PSP games onto your PS3 and then connect your Vita. Using Content Manager you should be able to use Copy from PS3 to copy over most PSP games (not Minis, not PS1 games) onto your Vita, even if they're not available for direct download.

Some PSP games are still not available however; I found some games didn't copy over via this method. The following games didn't transfer from my library (not an exhaustive list):

- Patapon 3
- Wipeout Pure
- Pixeljunk Monsters

Comment: I don't know whether you can do this with a PC and Media Go but it's worth a shot. I'll try and find out later.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It would be most desirable to possibly have a list of unsupported PSP games or official confirmation concerning Vita's PSP compatibility. From my point of view it is extremely strange that only a small percentage of PSP games are not supported, even though these games (such as Wipeout Pure or Patapon 3) are not really using any kind of very PSP-specific functionality.

Comment: @sarmackie yeah I don't know why. Patapon 3 uses online features so maybe that's why? I don't think the others do though.  Maybe they're working on support which is why they're not in the PSP/Vita section on the PSN store. FWIW I've had no problems playing the other games that DID transfer.

Answer (score 1):

The psp list is touch and go. I dl splinter cell essentials and pursuit force,and they transferred. I dl metal gear portable ops and it wouldn't transfer.the same goes for minis.