# Does PSVita not support PSOne classic games?

Tags: psn, ps1, ps-vita

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the Vita's backwards compatibility with PSP games extend to PS1 games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49972/does-the-vitas-backwards-compatibility-with-psp-games-extend-to-ps1-games)

Amazon's description of the PS Vita states:

> Vita can play PSP titles, minis, PS one classics, video and comics from the PlayStation Store

However, when I log into my PSN account on my new Vita, go to the store and my download history, for Final Fantasy IX it says:

> Cannot download using a PS Vita system

Is Amazon's description incorrect, or is there some workaround for this?

Comment: Possible duplicates - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49972/does-the-vitas-backwards-compatibility-with-psp-games-extend-to-ps1-games and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/51577/are-all-psn-psp-games-compatible-with-ps-vita